# $_POST in array?

Tags: php, arrays, post, foreach

I have a script that put some terms into an array and then into the database.
Below you find a snippet. Everything is working fine, but i cannot get the $*POST code to work correctly. What i need is that it contains the value of 'app*' combined with the $album['id'] that is submitted by a form. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong here. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
global $wpdb;
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );

$albums = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM wp_wppa_albums WHERE owner = "' . get_author_name( $post_author_id ) .'"' ), ARRAY_A );
$input_terms = array(); 
if ( $albums ) foreach( $albums as $album ) {

$input_terms[] = 'app_'.$_POST[$album['id']]; //This goes wrong


}
```

Comment: You should show your HTML code as well (and tag the question with html and php).

Comment: probably wan to to var_dump($_POST)  and share

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies. This works for instance `$input_terms[] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['app_1'] );` . The foreach function works (tested it) but for some reason i cannot make PHP populate a variable like the one given.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, my bad. Was an easy fix

```
$input_terms[] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['app_'.$album['id']]);
```

Worked for me!